# how to post selected values using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="1" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var selected_value = []; // initialize empty array 
    $(".source:checked").each(function(){
      selected_value.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(selected_value); //Press F12 to see all selected values
  });
</script>
```

I want to submit this form. At the time of submission all the checked checkbox values need to be inserted in to a table in a database. How can I do it properly?

Comment: where is your `ajax` call ?

Comment: You need to write some server side code to handle the form data and connect to your database. As you've tagged the question with PHP, I'd start your research with that. Also note that jQuery's `map()` method is a much more succinct method of building an array

Comment: First of all I would suggest you to move all inputs into the `<form></form>`

Answer (score 0):

This code is good resolve your problem :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected_value = []; // initialize empty array 
    $(".source").change(function(){
        if( $( this ).is( ":checked" ) ){
            console.log($(this).val());
            selected_value.push($(this).val());
        }else{
            selected_value.splice(selected_value.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
        }
        console.log(selected_value); //Press F12 to see all selected values
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where the ajax call question is 'selected values using ajax'

Comment: Where is the ajax function he asked for??

Answer (score 0):

- First set those inputs inside `<form></form>`
- Where is your ajax call?

Don't forget to include ajax before you can run ajax calls.
Add this to your head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This should be your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "your php url where it saves the values to the DB",
   data: {"selected values": selected_value},
   type: "POST",
   error:function(xhr){alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText); },
   success: function(data){ // do your things on succes }   
});`
```

You should update the array everytime you check/uncheck a checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var selected_value = []; // initialize empty array 
   $(".source").change(function(){
      if( $( this ).is( ":checked" ) ){
          selected_value.push($(this).val()); // add to array
       }else{
          selected_value.splice(selected_value.indexOf($(this).val()), 1); // find position and remove from array
       }
       console.log(selected_value); //Press F12 to see all selected values
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename your checkboxes to array format since they already have same names.

**Change:**

```
name="type"
```

**To:**

```
name="type[]"
```

You can use `jQuery serialize()` to convert your checkbox array into query string that can be used in transmitting data from ajax to a PHP file.

Try this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="4" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="3" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="5" />
<input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='submit']").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
                url:'ajax-pdo-process.php', 
                method:'POST',
                data: $('input[name="type[]"]').serialize(),
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                   }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

To save the data coming from ajax, you can use PDO in your PHP file. Below is the template you can use. Name it `ajax-pdo-process.php`.

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'dbusername','dbpassword');
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl(c0, c2) VALUES(:c0, :c1);');
    $stmt->bindValue(':c0', $_POST['type'][0]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':c1', $_POST['type'][1]);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

^ I added `print_r($_POST);` so you know which values are being sent to your PHP handler.